# multiple definition of namespace variable, C++ compilation

Tags: c++

I m writing a simple Makefile which looks like this

```
CC=gcc
CXX=g++
DEBUG=-g
COMPILER=${CXX}
a.out: main.cpp Mail.o trie.o Spambin.o
        ${COMPILER}  ${DEBUG} main.cpp Mail.o trie.o Re2/obj/so/libre2.so

trie.o: trie.cpp
        ${COMPILER}  ${DEBUG} -c trie.cpp

Mail.o: Mail.cpp
        ${COMPILER} ${DEBUG} -c Mail.cpp

Spambin.o: Spambin.cpp
        ${COMPILER} ${DEBUG} -c Spambin.cpp

clean: 
        rm -f *.o
```

I have a file name config.h which is required in `Mail.cpp` and `Spambin.cpp`, so I have 
`#include "config.h"` in both `Mail.cpp` and `Spambin.cpp`. `config.h` looks like this:

```
#ifndef __DEFINE_H__
#define __DEFINE_H__

#include<iostream>

namespace config{
        int On = 1;
        int Off = 0;

        double S = 1.0;
}
#endif
```

---

```
But when I try to compile the code it gives me
Mail.o:(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `config::On'
/tmp/ccgaS6Bh.o:(.data+0x8): first defined here
Mail.o:(.data+0x10): multiple definition of `config::Off'
/tmp/ccgaS6Bh.o:(.data+0x10): first defined here
```

Can any one help me debug this?

Comment: I've removed the `[c]` tag since the question has nothing whatsoever to do with C.

Comment: Do you really have two **variables** called on and off? Or are those constants? If they are constants you should make them so and the problem would go away. Well, you would be left with the issue of S

Comment: You shouldn't use reserved names for your include guards.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can not assign to namespace variables in a header files. Doing that *defines* the variables instead of just *declaring* them. Put that in a separate source file and add that to the Makefile and it should work.

**Edit** Also, you have to make the *declarations* in the header file `extern`.

So in the header file the namespace should look like this:

```
namespace config{
    extern int On;
    extern int Off;

    extern double S;
}
```

And in the source file:

```
namespace config{
    int On = 1;
    int Off = 0;

    double S = 1.0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean, "cannot _initialize_ namespace variables in header files"? Even this change is not sufficient. A declaration without an initializer is a definition unless `extern` is explicitly used.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Remembered about `extern` just the same time you wrote your comment.

Comment: @CharlesBailey aren't variables `extern` by default?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: They have external linkage by default but that's not the only effect that `extern` has on declarations.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I made the changes as u said but now both the .o compilation says the config is not defined. Can you please tell how the makefile should look. The error is `/Mail.cpp:194: undefined reference to `config::EnvironRecipientVarName /Mail.cpp:195: undefined reference to config::EnvironSenderVarName`

Comment: @Piyush Add the source file just like the other source files in the Makefile. For example, copy the lines for used for trie.cpp and change the name to your new source file. Remember to add the object file to the command where you link your application.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: just compiled it, its working fine. Forgot to make changes to Makefile. Thanks for help

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Variable definition in header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216765/variable-definition-in-header-files)

You have to put your variable definition, i.e. the value assignment in a source file or protect it with a #ifdef guard for not being defined twice when included in separate source files.

Answer (score 3):

In your header file, declare ***const*** your 3 variables.
For example, like this :

```
#ifndef __DEFINE_H__
#define __DEFINE_H__

#include<iostream>

namespace config{
        const int On = 1;
        const int Off = 0;

        const double S = 1.0;
}
#endif
```

Comment: I think the problem with this answer is that if you do this, they are no longer _variables_. However as a replacement for `#define` constants, this seems to me like a reasonable way to go.