# Qt Duplicate symbols found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, qt

I have a header file for the namespace `Segmentation` called `segmentation.h`. The functions declared in the header are defined in the implementation file `segmentation.cpp`. The namespace is used in `mainwindow.cpp` and hence it has been included in the said file. But when I am trying to compile project, I get

> `1 duplicate symbols found for architecture x86_64`

I do understand `duplicate symbols found for architecture x86_64` errors occur when you try to include a module multiple times during linkage. But I have only included `segmentation.h` only once in the above mentioned file.

segmentation.h

```
#ifndef SEGMENTATION_H
#define SEGMENTATION_H

#include <QObject>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <QPixmap>

namespace Segmentation
{
    int k;
    cv::Mat getSegments(cv::Mat inputImage);
    cv::Mat sampleInput(cv::Mat &inputImage);
}

#endif // SEGMENTATION_H
```

segmentation.cpp

```
#include "segmentation.h"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

cv::Mat Segmentation::getSegments(cv::Mat inputImage)
{

    Segmentation::sampleInput(inputImage);

    //Incomplete code

    return inputImage;
}

cv::Mat Segmentation::sampleInput(cv::Mat &inputImage)
{
    std::cout << "Size: " << inputImage.size << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Rows: " << inputImage.rows << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Cols: " << inputImage.cols << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Size rows x cols: " << inputImage.rows * inputImage.cols << std::endl;

    //Incomplete code

    return inputImage;
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_loadImageButton_clicked();
    void on_clearScreenButton_clicked();
    void on_segmentButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    cv::Mat _rawInputImage;
    QPixmap _inputImage;
    QPixmap _outputImage;
    QGraphicsScene _scene;
    QGraphicsPixmapItem _inputImagePixmapItem;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QRectF>
#include <segmentation.h>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):QMainWindow(parent),ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    MainWindow::setWindowState(Qt::WindowFullScreen);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_loadImageButton_clicked()
{
    QFileDialog fileDialog(this, Qt::Dialog);
    fileDialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::ExistingFile);
    fileDialog.setNameFilter("*.jpg *.png *.jpeg");
    fileDialog.setViewMode(QFileDialog::Detail);
    fileDialog.exec();

    QStringList selectedFileName = fileDialog.selectedFiles();
    QString selectedFile = selectedFileName.at(0);
    _inputImage.load(selectedFile);
    _rawInputImage = cv::imread(selectedFile.toStdString());

    _inputImagePixmapItem.setPixmap((_inputImage));
    _scene.addItem(&_inputImagePixmapItem);
    this->ui->inputImageViewWidget->setScene(&_scene);
    this->ui->inputImageViewWidget->fitInView(&_inputImagePixmapItem, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

    fileDialog.saveState();
    return;
}

void MainWindow::on_clearScreenButton_clicked()
{
    _scene.removeItem(&_inputImagePixmapItem);
    return;
}

void MainWindow::on_segmentButton_clicked()
{
    cv::Mat segmentedOutputImage = Segmentation::getSegments(_rawInputImage);
}
```

Compile output

```
14:15:59: Running steps for project LaundroBotQt...
14:15:59: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
14:15:59: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -headerpad_max_install_names -stdlib=libc++ -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -Wl,-rpath,/Users/Vino/Documents/Qt/5.8/clang_64/lib -o LaundroBotQt.app/Contents/MacOS/LaundroBotQt main.o mainwindow.o segmentation.o moc_mainwindow.o   -F/Users/Vino/Documents/Qt/5.8/clang_64/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_ml -lopencv_flann -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_photo -framework QtWidgets -framework QtGui -framework QtCore -framework DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework OpenGL -framework AGL 
duplicate symbol __ZN12Segmentation1kE in:
    mainwindow.o
    segmentation.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [LaundroBotQt.app/Contents/MacOS/LaundroBotQt] Error 1
14:15:59: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project LaundroBotQt (kit: Desktop Qt 5.8.0 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
14:15:59: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

[GitHub repo link](https://github.com/vinokanth92/LaundroBot_Qt)

I am not quite sure how to fix this problem. I have read through StackOverflow, but my issue seems bizarre. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could share your project via github or gist so you can test it quickly.

Comment: Added GitHub repo link. Please check. Thanks.

Comment: Change `int k;` to `extern int k;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here, in segmentation.h:

```
namespace Segmentation
{
   int k;
   [...]
```

Here you are both declaring and defining storage for the variable named `k` in the Segmentation namespace.  The problem with that is that if more than one .cpp file #include's segmentation.h (which will almost certainly happen), then the variable Segmentation::k will have storage declared for it in more than one .cpp file, leading to the duplicate-symbols error you see.

To get around that problem, do this in segmentation.h instead:

```
namespace Segmentation
{
   extern int k;
   [...]
```

... and then in one of your .cpp files (probably segmentation.cpp would be the most appropriate one), add the storage separately, like this:

```
namespace Segmentation
{
   int k;
};
```

That way storage space for Segmentation::k will be allocated only in that one .cpp file instead of many of them.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971824/multiple-definition-of-namespace-variable-c-compilation

Comment: Thank you very much :) It fixed it. Not sure why its downvoted :/