# why there's no class redefinition error in link stage, compared to functions?

Tags: c++

As I know, if I define a non-inline function in `A.h` and include `A.h` in `main.cpp` and `A.cpp`. Then there will be **function redefinition error**.
Sample code like this:

A.h:

```
void hello(){}
```

A.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"
```

But why there's no **class redefinition error** if I define a class in `A.h`, include `A.h` in `main.cpp` and `A.cpp`?

A.h:

```
class A{};
```

A.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"
```

Do class process in a similar way like inline function (I know little about how inline function process but I've heard that inline functions have some marks, and compiler(or linker?) will delete all the other definition copies and leave one definition in the end)?

Comment: The linker doesn't care about class definitions, it only takes care of linking concrete functions.  It treats inline functions special, multiple copies are allowed but it emits only one.  Same story for the vtable.

Comment: It's OK because the language specification says it's OK.

Comment: contrast [`[basic.def.odr]/10`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#10) with [`[basic.def.odr]/12`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#12)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is there no multiple definition error when you define a class in a header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654377/why-is-there-no-multiple-definition-error-when-you-define-a-class-in-a-header-fi)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways of answering this question.  We can look at the C++ standard to see what the rules say, and we can look at the actual implementation of a compiler to see why this happens in practice.

- If we're looking at the C++ standard, there is a rule known as the [One Definition Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule), or the ODR. The ODR says that classes may be defined in more than one translation unit, but the definitions must be identical (using `.h` files makes it easy to guarantee this).  But non-inline functions may only be defined in a single translation unit.
- If we're looking at the actual implementation of a compiler, the reason for this behavior is simple.  A class definition does not output anything into a `.o` file (except maybe some debugging information).  A function definition, on the other hand, outputs some compiled object code along with a symbol table entry.

You can see this in action if you inspect the contents of your object file:

```
$ cat test.cc
class Foo {};
void hello() {}
$ g++ -c -o test.o test.cc
$ nm test.o
0000000000000000 T __Z5hellov
```

In `test.cc` I defined both a class and a function.  But the class didn't emit anything into the object file, only the function did.  That's why there is no conflict when two `.o` files define the same class.

Inline functions require special processing to avoid causing link errors.  They are put in special sections known as COMDAT sections.  You can read more about this [here](https://www.airs.com/blog/archives/52).

Comment: nice example. better answer than the duplicated question. Thanks!

Comment: A class definition can definitely output linker symbols. Two common outputs are RTTI information and vtables.

Comment: RTTI and vtables are typically only emitted when a non-inline virtual function is defined. A class definition alone typically won't do it unless all virtual methods are defined inline, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23746941/what-is-the-meaning-of-clangs-wweak-vtables