# Variable already defined in .obj; What is going on here?

Tags: c++, variables, c++14, declaration, definition

head.h

```
#pragma once

namespace foo
{
    int bar;

    int funct1();
}
```

head.cpp

```
#include "head.h"

int foo::funct1()
{
    return bar;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "head.h"


int main()
{
    foo::bar = 1;
    std::cout << foo::funct1() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Error   LNK2005 "int foo::bar" (?bar@foo@@3HA) already defined in head.obj

I don't understand what is going on. I tried looking for the answer but everyone's questions are so specific to their code and don't even look close to the problem that I am having.

I am not including .cpp files into main. I am not redefining anything. I am literally just assigning 1 to the variable then returning it with a function in the same namespace. How is it being defined multiple times?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable definition in header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216765/variable-definition-in-header-files)

Comment: *How is it being defined multiple times?* -- You must have not realized what `#pragma once` is supposed to do.  It doesn't mean "this is only declared once in my entire program".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable definition in header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216765/variable-definition-in-header-files)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The header `head.h` is included in two compilation units `head.cpp` and `main.cpp`. So the variable `bar` is defined twice. You could declare the variable without its definition the following way

```
#pragma once

namespace foo
{
    extern int bar;

    int funct1();
}
```

and then define it in some cpp module.

Comment: Thank you. I never actually used this before on a variable. I couldn't understand how it was a problem since it is not a problem with classes or structs.

Comment: @JwGaming Types and objects are two different things.

Comment: @JwGaming *it is not a problem with classes or structs.* -- It certainly is a problem with classes and structs if you had done the same thing.  `struct foo {}; foo f;`  If you had that in a header, you would have gotten the same error.

Answer (score 4):

This `foo` namespace-level `bar` declaration:

```
namespace foo
{
    int bar;
}
```

is actually a **definition**.

To make it a declaration, mark the `bar` as `extern` in *head.h*:

```
namespace foo
{
    extern int bar;
}
```

Then define it in *head.cpp*:

```
int foo::bar = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

`head.h` is included in *both* main.cpp and head.cpp.
So the variable is defined twice.

Possible Solution: make it inline. The "extern" solutions are also good, although older in approach.

```
namespace foo
{
    inline int bar;
}
```

Comment: This gave me an error: Requires stdC++17
Only allowed on functions.

Comment: @JwGaming If you are using an old standard & toolchain, please state that in the question. It's 2019 now!

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit I am using the most up-to-date version of visual studio 2019...

Comment: Then flick it into C++17 mode!

Answer (score 2):

> How is it being defined multiple times?

It is defined once in head.cpp and once in main.cpp. That is a total of two times. This violates the one definition rule, which states that there may only be one definition for every variable.

> ```
> int bar;
> ```

This is a definition of a variable. You've included it into two translation units.

A variable can be declared without definition in an extern declaration:

```
extern int bar;
```

Replace the definition with such declaration, and put the definition into exactly one translation unit.

Answer (score 2):

> I am not redefining anything. I am literally just assigning 1 to the variable

You're redefining the variable!

`head.cpp` has one via `#include "head.h"`, and `main.cpp` has one via `#include "head.h"`.

You need to [merely *declare* it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23346307/560648) (unusual but not too strange) in the header:

```
extern int bar;
```

…then define it in *one* translation unit. This is just like what you do with `static` class members (albeit with slightly different syntax).

Since C++17, [you may do this by instead plopping the `inline` keyword on to your definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47502744/560648).

Alternatively, avoid mutable globals…

Comment: I had no idea there was a difference. I assumed it /was/ a declaration and that it became defined the moment it was given a value and not before. Only that the compiler needed a way to link all the uses together as it would not be used before the first time it was given a value.

Comment: @JwGaming It's an old wives' tale that the first assignment to an object is a "definition" or "initialisation". It's not; it's an assignment to an object that was already defined and constructed (and potentially default-constructed) previously. Most variable declarations are also definitions; we can use `extern` to suppress the definition part.

Answer (score 1):

Do carefully note that `foo` is not a class, but a namespace. When you declare a free variable in the header file:

`int bar;`

And then #include this header file multiple times (into different CPP files, causing multiple translation unit compilations), you'd get a linker error. Everyone knows it.

And, you'd add `extern` attribute at the declaration, and *define* the variable elsewhere in one of the CPP/C file.

Putting a global variable into a namespace is nothing but giving the **global** variable a different name. Think if `foo::bar` as `foo__NS__bar`, and hence you must add `extern` in the header and *define* `foo::bar` at some locatoin.

Note that this is different from a non-static member variable of a class. A class variable doesn't need to be defined/declared this way since the class is a **type**. Each instantiated variable of class-type would have a separate copy of the variable. 
Further to that, when you add a `static` variable in the class, you are giving that *logically*  **global** variable another name. Thence, you must have that static-variable *defined* one of the CPP file.